# Tensorflow Retrain the retrained model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am very new to Neural network and tensorflow, just starting on the retrain image tutorial. I have successfully completed the flower_photos training and i have 2 questions.

1.) Is it a good/bad idea to keep building upon a retrained model many times over and over? Or would it be a lot better to train a model fresh everytime? That leads to my second question

2.) If it is ok to retrain a model over and over, for the retrain model tutorial in Tensorflow (Image_retraining), in the retrain.py would i simply replace the classify_image_graph_def.pb and imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt with the one outputted from my retraining? But i see that there is also a imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt, would i have to replace that one with something else?

Thanks for your time

Comment: did you ever figure this out?